# Unknown Host Exception DNS Error

Tags: java, xml, web, host, connectivity

I am trying to connect to the service

https://staging.identitymanagement.lexisnexis.com/identity-proofing/services/identityProofingServiceWS/v2

which is a web service hosted by Lexis Nexis.

Following exception is encountered.

```
  staging.identitymanagement.lexisnexis.com (java.net.UnknownHostException)
  java.net.PlainSocketImpl:177 (null)
  Initialisation Failure: staging.identitymanagement.lexisnexis.com
  java.net.UnknownHostException: staging.identitymanagement.lexisnexis.com
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:177)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:550)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.
      connect      (BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:272)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.
     getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
```

I am trying to call the same  using mule integration services.However, we are still getting this issue for Unknown Host Exception.
I have also correctly added the proxy details for the same.

Please guide me the way ahead.

Comment: How are you trying to connect (code) and how have you added the proxy details?

Comment: the link seems to be wrong. It's pointing to some `xml` file. It needs to be a service only then will you get a response.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a network proxy issue to me.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Have you added proxy into your vm arguments(JAVA_OPTIONS) in the server startup script?
It should look something like this.

```
JAVA_FLAGS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=hostname.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
java ${JAVA_FLAGS} ...
```

I also recommend setting the proxies programmatically,

```
public void setProxy() {
    if (isUseHTTPProxy()) {
        // HTTP/HTTPS Proxy
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", getHTTPHost());
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", getHTTPPort());
        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", getHTTPHost());
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", getHTTPPort());
        if (isUseHTTPAuth()) {
            String encoded = new String(Base64.encodeBase64((getHTTPUsername() + ":" + getHTTPPassword()).getBytes()));
            con.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
            Authenticator.setDefault(new ProxyAuth(getHTTPUsername(), getHTTPPassword()));
        }
    }
```